# Agent runs unknown build we're not aware of

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

**Description**

For some reason my .Net Build Agent randomly gets disconnected and I see this message (please see the screenshot):

> Agent runs unknown build we're not aware of

[image]

**Question**

- What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Please, include more details about your network setup of the TeamCity server and its agent. Include also relevant logs from TeamCity Agent directory.

Comment: Please create issue in [TeamCity bug tracker|https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW] and attach teamcity-agent.log and teamcity-server.log files. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be related to some security concerns also, I was trying to manually run the build multiple times, then I started getting this error. What I did was:

- Clicked on the 3 dots next to the <kbd>Run</kbd> button.
- Selected `run as a personal build` and `put the build to the queue top`.
- Tried again.

[image]

Comment: "What is the reason for this behavior?"
I don't see how this answers the question.